# How to handle new time zone?

Tags: datetime, time, timezone

We have a database of cities with its geo coordinates. Once we filled it with corresponding time zones using [tzworld](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/). User sets location including city, city has time zone - here how we know user's timezone (we need to render date and time on server). But time zones are being changed: some new are appearing, some old are being removed.

**Is there any best practices or tools to handle that kind of changes?**

I.e. there is a city `Foo` with time zone `Foo/Bar`. One day tzdata was changed, and `Foo/Bar` was split into `Foo/Old_Bar` and `Foo/New_Bar` time zones with the same UTC offsets. We still have `Foo/Bar` in our db. Actually, it's a BC break, but it's ok since, say, we can handle those BC breaks. But then tzdata was changed again, and now `Foo/New_Bar` has different offset. And here comes troubles. Some users from `Foo` city see wrong local time since that moment.

Just to be sure you understand me right: **it's not about DST, it's about the fact that time zones (their names) are being changed**.

As far as I can see, wee need a kind of machine-readable tzdata diff. Like

```
split: Foo/Bar Foo/Old_Bar,Foo/New_Bar
move:  Foo/New_Bar -05:00
```

This issue makes me feel that storing time zones is a bad idea. Is there a better one?

Comment: Don't good date libraries do this already? (Keep track of time zone changes and such) Can you make a specific example where `Foo/New_Bar` can have two different offsets for the same date? Is this a real world issue you are having? (I'm not saying it isn't - I'm just having a hard time imagining where it may apply)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's not a real world issue so far (mainly because most of our users are from regions with stable time zones), but it easily can be. I've accidentally noticed that some time zones dissapeared and some appeared after recent tzdata update. I want to have a robust solution, and that possible issue and especially lack of information on it haunts me.

Comment: But do you really have a use case where this could be a problem? If you have a date and time, then your ibrary should be able to resolve it to one point in time (and the it should be able to handle [crazy edge cases;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333) developers [spend a lot of time](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/09/30/the-mysteries-of-bcl-time-zone-data/) making sure that they do). If a zone disappears or is added, the library should have a list of these changes. Is this really something you need to handle in your application?

Comment: @Pekka웃 See the excellent and exhaustive answer by Matt Johnson, it helps you understand the issue, I wouldn't tell better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With specific regard to the IANA/Olson TZ database, the location identifiers do not change once established.  The history of each identifier is always consistent *for that location*.

However, if you are using tz_world or some other map source to determine the time zone for some *other* location - one that doesn't necessarily have it's *own* identifier, then yes - it's possible that a zone split will cause the zone to change.  Though, when it does, the new zone should be consistent with the old zone, up to the point of the change.

As a real world example, consider `America/Fort_Nelson`, which was added in tzdb 2015g for Fort Nelson, British Columbia, Canada, and the surrounding region of the Northern Rockies Regional Municipality.  Previously, this area would have been resolved to `America/Vancouver`, but the zone was split due to [their March 2015 time change](http://www.northernrockies.ca/EN/meta/news/archives/2015/northern-rockies-time-change.html).  The tz_world maps were updated on November 7, 2015 to account for this change.

- If you had previously resolved a user in Fort Nelson to `America/Vancouver`, then they will have incorrect times from November 1st, 2015 forward, as that's when Vancouver switched back to UTC-8, while Fort Nelson remained at UTC-7.
- If you update to the latest tzdb and tz_world, you can use the original information to re-determine the time zone - which would now be `America/Fort_Nelson`.
- The new time zone will accurately reflect all of the same information as Vancouver before the split, and the correct information for Fort Nelson after the split.

All of this should just work, assuming you update time zones after each update of tz_world, and recalculate future events after updating the tzdb.

The question remains, how do you know which zones have split and changed so you don't have to recalculate *everything*?  For a small amount of data, you might as well recalculate everything.  But for larger datasets, this might be impractical.  Unfortunately, there's no machine-readable standardized format for the differences.  I believe this has been talked about before in [the tz discussion list](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), but I can't find it at the moment.  You can ask there if you like.

Currently the only way is to manually read the release notes of each update.  You can find them in [the tz-announce list archives](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/) (or subscribe to the list for future updates).  You can also find them in the `NEWS` file of any given release.  You'll also want to review the history of the tz_world shapefile, which is on that web site.

Also, recognize that time zone IDs will never be *removed* from the tzdb.  A split may create a new zone (`Foo/New_Bar`), but the original zone will remain (`Foo/Bar`, not `Foo/Old_Bar`).  If a zone is determined unnecessary, its `Zone` entry might be replaced with a `Link` entry, but it will never be removed entirely.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot! Actually, that split with Fort Nelson is exactly the case that made me think of the whole issue and ask that question here.